# Error message while trying to apply "mclogit"

Tags: mixed-model

I am trying to find if the age and the sex influence the headache during the heatwaves. I tried to use

```r
mclogit::mclogit(Headache ~ Age+Sex, data=Headache)
```

The levels for Headache are " No", "Yes, inside" and "Yes, outside".
I changed those in 0 for "no", 1 for inside and -1 for outside. The error I get is **"Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable"**
How can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Did you call `summary()` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I did. The error is the same.